# AsyncHttpClient/curl command execution through java is not giving properly result

Tags: curl, java-8, asynchttpclient

I have a curl command like below (sample one)

```
curl -v https://my-ip/sample/v1/map/1?name=sat&id=123&code=AE123, ER345
```

When I execute above curl command directly its giving complete response(contains more than 2 pages) but when I am executing the above curl in java using `AsyncHttpClient` it is giving 2 lines of response only. Sample Code

```
    private static void executeHttps(String map, String codes) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "https://my-ip/sample/v1/map/"+channelMap;
    AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder r = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url);
    r.addQueryParam("name", "sat");
    r.addQueryParam("id", "123");
    r.addQueryParam("codes", codes);
    logger.info("URL: "+r);
    Future<Response> f = r.execute();

    Response res = f.get();

    logger.info(res.getStatusCode() + ": " + res.getStatusText());
    logger.info(res.getResponseBody());
}
```

I also tried to implement the code which will directly execute as a curl command in java i.e

```
String curlString = "curl -v https://my-ip/sample/v1/map/1?name=sat&id=123&code=AE123, ER345";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(curlString);
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
String s = jsonString = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
```

When I print `json` value it is giving the same response as `AsyncHttpClient`. Not able to get actual response in both the cases. Here another point is when I change `codes` values in the `curl` command I will get different response(for some codes I am getting same response in direct curl and in program but for codes getting different responses in direct curl and program curl).

I also tried to use `HttpUrlConnection` and `HttpsUrlConnection` but still facing same issue

Comment: curl command might returns with html tags and everything

Comment: No, it is returning response in Json format only